# How to determine if the clicked element is a child of some ID?

Tags: jquery

How can I determine whether this clicked element is a subset of somemenu ?

#### jQuery Example:

```
var clicked = e.target;

// this checks see if the clicked has id of somemenu.
$(clicked).attr("id") == '#somemenu';
```

#### HTML example of somemenu:

```
<div id="somemenu">
   <a href="something.php"> menu 1 </a>
   <!--bunch of other elements here, can be anything.-->
</div>
```

I want to catch any element that is subset of `div#somemenu? when it's clicked.

Comment: What does your full event handler look like, is it on `document`...if so is placing it directly on `#somemenu` an option?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will work:

```
if ($(clicked).parents('#somemenu').length) {
    // I am a child of somemenu so do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's more easy work with `stopPropagation` and the method `on` of jquery:

```
jQuery('#myID').on('click',"*",function(e){
          e.stopPropagation(); //stop the propagation          
          console.log("Clicked element: ",jQuery(this)); //get the element clicked by the mouse
          console.log("Parent: ",jQuery(this).closest("#myID"));

});
```

if you don't stop the propagation you should call to all parents of the `jQuery(this);`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is a bit cleaner and more readable IMHO

```
if($.contains(someElement, clicked)){ // DO STUFF }
```

Comment: If your elements are jQuery objects, you have to pull the DOM element like myjQueryObject[0].